# NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM not found

Tags: sql-server, windows-8.1, windows-administration

I'm trying to add "`NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`" to `MSSQL` Database, and it fails with error:

```
Windows NT user or group 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' not found. Check the name again.
```

Query string:

```
CREATE LOGIN [NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
```

How is it possible not to have this win user ?

Comment: Check if this helps - http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=191253

Answer (score -1):

I read microsoft documentation about this kind of situation, and the only solution is to re-install windows, because NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM appears only once - at windows installation. So i guess we can close this question.

Comment: Reinstalling Windows is unlikely to be the right answer.  Windows *always* has SYSTEM - although it isn't actually an account.  Either you're adding it in the wrong way (did you try sp_grantlogon?) or there's some problem with the SQL installation.